# theme_preprocess_node function not getting executed from template file

Tags: nodes, theming

I am trying to print action "tabs" in my node.tpl.php file. I added the preprocess function as below-

function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {

```
 $variables['page_tabs'] = menu_local_tabs();
```

}

Then trying to print in my tpl like below.

```
print $page_tabs;
```

But it is not getting executed at all. Infect the control is not going inside preprocess function when I am trying to exit like below-

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {

 echo "good bye";
 exit;
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For using this hook, u will have to replace MYTHEME with your theme name, like if your theme name is bartik, then your function will be

```
bartik_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook)
```

After that clear your cache, by going to Configuration >> Development >> Performance

or just write in url admin/config/development/perfromance

Comment: I tried that but its not happening.

Comment: What is your theme name, where r u writing this code..?

Comment: I am using bootstrap theme. And I am adding a new file node.vars.php under theme/system folder.

Comment: Dont create node.vars.php, try to write this function in template.php file

Comment: Tried that too.

Comment: Check that the page which u want to show is actually node page, or someother page

Comment: It is not printing in node/edit nor in node/view page my friend.